# c# linq group by a datetime to the nearest second

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I would like to group the following datetimes together using Linq in c# as follows:

Group 1:

```
2015-03-03 15:18:42.880
2015-03-03 15:18:42.897
```

Group 2:

```
2015-03-19 16:29:59.977
2015-03-19 16:29:59.983
2015-03-19 16:29:59.983
```

Group 3:

```
2015-03-26 11:27:29.813
2015-03-26 11:27:30.030
2015-03-26 11:27:30.030
```

Group 4:

```
2015-03-27 15:13:58.483
2015-03-27 15:13:58.483
2015-03-27 15:13:58.500
```

I'm having an issue with some of these groupings.  Currently I'm just grouping the dates ignoring the milliseconds portion.  What I would like to do it group dates which are within 1 second of each other without the milliseconds.
This is my query so far:

```
var query =
from trans in TransactionTable.AsEnumerable()                                                        
let dateWithoutMilliseconds = trans.Field<DateTime>("TranactionDate").AddMilliseconds(-trans.Field<DateTime>("TranactionDate").Millisecond)
group trans by dateWithoutMilliseconds into g
select new
{                                   
TransDate = g.Key,                                                                
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "What I would like to do it group dates which are within 1 second of each other without the milliseconds." Do you mean group to the nearest whole second? Because that will still group dates which are within a second of each other in different groups, e.g. 2015-03-26 11:27:29.513 and 2015-03-26 11:27:29.413 - they're only 100ms apart, but the first would round up to 2015-03-26 11:27:30 and the second would round down to 2015-03-26 11:27:29.

Comment: So if you have 2015-03-03 15:18:42.880, 2015-03-03 15:18:43.000 to 2015-03-03 20:00:00.000 continuous data all with just 1 sec difference, will you group this into 1?

Comment: The desired result is not clear; perhaps you would like to create the groups base on some criterion which depends on the data itself, which is called [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Comment: I modified my original post to add another grouping. Looking at your examples I need to take into account the millisecond value. 
   I guess what I'm trying to do it group dates where there is range of 200-300ms (the exact range has yet to be decided).  
   I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach.

Comment: A second is a fraction of a day which is 1/(24 * 60 * 60) which is an irrational number.  I would truncate the string removing the fractional part of the second which would be rounding down and not worrying rounding the fraction of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `Ticks` (100 nano seconds), round up, and then back to `DateTime`. In case you want just to `GroupBy` just round up `Tick`s:

```
DateTime source = ...
...
// Up to nearest second
const int shift = 10000000;

DateTime result = new DateTime(
  (source.Ticks / shift + (source.Ticks % shift >= (shift / 2) ? 1 : 0)) * shift);

// If you want just a key to group by
long key = (source.Ticks / shift + (source.Ticks % shift >= (shift / 2) ? 1 : 0)) * shift;
```